# How to backup my Yocto Project forSystem embedded

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

After installing the whole Yocto Project for my Linux Embedded board (specifically a VARISCITE DART 6UL that features a i.MX6ULL Cortex A7), I'd like to backup all on an external HDD.
I tried, but after more than 8 hours backup wasn't completed; thus I checked property of "var-fslc-yocto" folder, and it didn't stop to check its dimension (after twenty minutes number of counted files and total amount of memory used was in progress).
The same for other folders, i.e. for kernel and poky.
My question is: what I'm doing wrong? Is there a best or correct way to backup Tocto Project structure to avoid to loose all my work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with tar :

> tar cvzf /path/to/yourexternaldisk/projectbackup.tar.gz
> /path/to/yourproject